# Help in understanding a sentence about TCR-MHC interaction and immune synapse formation

Tags: immunology

> T-cell co-stimulatory and co-inhibitory molecules (collectively named co-signaling molecules) play a crucial role in regulating T-cell activation, subset differentiation, effector function and survival. Following recognition of cognate peptide-MHC complexes on antigen-presenting cells by the T-cell receptor, co-signaling receptors co-localize with T-cell receptors at the immune synapse, where they synergize with TCR signaling to promote or inhibit T-cell activation and function.

I'm not sure I understand the second sentence. The language is a little confusing to me. Does it mean that after a TCR binds to a peptide-MHC complex, other TCRs present on the cell gather around that TCR? Does it mean that one TCR can bind more than one peptide-MHC complex (which, as far as I understand, isn't true)?

Here's my paraphrase of this sentence:

> Following recognition of **a cognate peptide-MHC complex** on **an antigen-presenting cell** by **a T-cell receptor**, co-signaling receptors co-localize with **(other) T-cell receptors** at the immune synapse, where they synergize with TCR signaling to promote or inhibit T-cell activation and function.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that after a TCR binds to a peptide-MHC complex, other TCRs present on the cell gather around that TCR?

Yes. Other TCRs bind other MHC/antigen complexes and they all cluster together, forming an [immunological synapse](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4692051/).

> Does it mean that one TCR can bind more than one peptide-MHC complex (which, as far as I understand, isn't true)?

No. TCR:MHC bind 1:1.

Your final paraphrase is correct.